# How to add dynamic row next to the clicked row with react + redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, accordion

I'm creating a collapsible table, when the user click on a row, the details are fetched with an api call and the details has to displayed as a new table below to that row (Like accordion). Clicking again closes that opened row and this happens for every row (the data being served on request). 
Can anyone suggest me a way to achieve this with React + Redux

```
<tbody>
                {projectslist.map( i =>
                   [<tr key={Math.random()} id={'row_'+i.id} onClick={toggleDetail(i.id)}>
                        <td key={Math.random()} md={1} xs={1}>{i.name}</td>
                        <td className="totalCol" key={Math.random()} md={1} xs={1}>{i.value}</td>

                        {months.map(m => 
                            weeks.map(w => 
                                w == 1 ? [ <td colSpan="2">1/2</td>, <td key={Math.random()}>{calculateCells(w, m.format("M"), recordslist[i.name])}</td>]
                                : <td key={Math.random()}>{calculateCells(w, m.format("M"), recordslist[i.name])}</td>
                            )
                        )}
                   </tr>,
                   <tr id={'child_'+i.id} ref={'child_'+i.id} style={{display:'none'}}>Test

                   </tr>]
                )}
            </tbody>
```

Comment: Do you have any piece of working react code?

Comment: You can check React Table https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme

Comment: @EliâMelfior I've attached dynamic table code. Here for every row, onclick i need to load a dynamic content fetch thru api call into the hidden empty <tr> added next to every row

Comment: @AnnMary https://react-table.js.org/#/story/foldable-table-hoc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You want to store two things in your state: the state of the toggles and the data fetched from the server.
2. Create an action ([async action](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions)) to fetch data from the server. In addition the action should toggle the open state.
3. Create a reducer that stores the result from the fetch in your state
4. In `toggleDetail()` call your new action
5. Use `mapStateToProps` to map the state to your props. Use the open state to determine if you should render the row open or closed.

Since you want to implement an accordion and multiple rows can be open at once I would suggest the following data structure for your state: (assuming data is the data fetched from the server): `state.projects[data.id] = data`.

Instead of two states for each row (open/closed) you can also introduce a third state `loading` to indicate to users that the data is currently being fetched from the server.